# MySQL Joining and Returning Rows Not Present in a Hard Coded List

Tags: mysql

I need some help with MySQL query. I have a list of product color ids and I want to find out which one of those don't exist in the database. The below query returns the matching colorids from the database. I want to see which of the colors don't exists in db.

```
select cs.imageid from colorids cs 
where cs.imageid in 
(
3333,
2222,
4444,
5555,
6666,
7777,
8888,
)
```

Comment: can't do it that way. you'd need to put those values into a temp table, then join that temptable against the other one. `in` is any "any" check. it won't tell you if something's "missing".

Comment: Remove the , at the end of the last row (8888,)

and say where NOT in (........)

Comment: Thanks! I inserted all the ImageIds in the temp table and then I said select from temp table where imageID not in actual table and it returned nothing. There is something else wrong I guess! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can hard-code your list this way, and then use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT list.colorid
FROM (
  SELECT 3333 colorid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444
) AS list LEFT JOIN colorids cs
ON list.colorid = cs.imageid
WHERE
  cs.imageid IS NULL
```